# <th> will not scroll horizontally with the rest of the table in IE8 in quirks mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode

I have a bug in my program's user interface which can only be recreated in browser mode IE8 and Document type "quirks mode".  I have never usually have to work with html/css so I am a little lost.

My code sample is a bit too large to fit comfortably on this page, but can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/wnq7TW2P).  I forgot to attach the relevant css which can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/js4bDHcZ).

At first glance, it appears that the `<thead>` does not scroll with the table.  after a look with IE8 dev tools, I found that the `<thead>` and `<tr>` elements are moving with the horizontal scroll bar as they should, but the child element `<th>` (first seen on line 19) is staying in place.

When I manually change specific attributes of the `<th>` tag, (e.g. align, text-align), all of a sudden, the table headers will scroll properly.  When I try to implement these in the code, they do not fix the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless your page is making Internet Explorer drop from standards mode into quirks mode, you shouldn't worry about making it work in that mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a company requirement.

Comment: In that case you should ask the company why it is a requirement. IE quirks mode is the equivalent of IE 5.5! Microsoft have totally forgotten about IE5.5 and are trying to [kill off IE6!](http://www.ie6countdown.com) There is absolutely no reason that your page should work in BOTH standards mode and quirks mode.

Comment: I am intrigued to know what came of this. Did you explain why it is silly to want this.

Comment: Yes, I explained that we shouldn't have to do it for both.  I explained that just because one QA tester found a defect while messing with ie8 developer settings, we shouldn't make changes which could risk the functionality we already have.  Thanks you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit overflow on the th:

```
th { overflow: scroll; height:1%; }
```

Here is the difference:

> Overflow is treated by expanding a box. When the content of an element does not fit into the dimensions specified for it (explicitly or implicitly), then overflow: visible (the default) means that the content overflows while the box dimensions are as specified. In Quirks Mode, the dimensions change; this can easily been seen e.g. if the box has a back­ground color or a border.

**References**

- [The table cell nowrap minimum width calculation quirk](http://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-table-cell-nowrap-minimum-width-calculation-quirk)
- [Quirks mode and Strict mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)
- [What happens in Quirks mode?](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html)
- [Rendering modes - overflow:visible (quirks)](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/modes/overflow_quirks.html)
- [IE/Win Unscrollable Content Bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/unscrollable.html)
- [IE7 Dehacker](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/ie7-dehacker.html)